# Entity object attached DbContext passed in param lost data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a mysterious issue.

I use Linq to Entities to get a user profile and send the result object to a function to fill it with MVC model data.

```
using (var db = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    try
    {
        var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == accorJobPrincipal.Id);
        //At the point, user.CreatedAt contains the right date
        user = model.GetBaseObject(user);
        //At the point, user.CreatedAt is equal to DateTime.MinValue (0001/01/01)

        user.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        db.SaveChanges(); //Here, I have an exception due to Overflow in SQL Datetime convert
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "A system error occured, please try later.");
    }
}
```

Why the entity object lost data when it passed as parameter ?

---

**EDIT** Please find here the code of GetBaseObject()

```
public override Users GetBaseObject(Users objectFromContext = default(Users))
    {
        var returnUser = objectFromContext ?? new Users();

        returnUser.FirstName = FirstName;
        returnUser.LastName = LastName;
        returnUser.IdTitle = IdTitle;
        returnUser.CreatedAt = CreatedAt;
        returnUser.UpdatedAt = UpdatedAt;
        returnUser.DeletedAt = DeletedAt;
        returnUser.LastConnectionAt = LastConnectionAt;
        returnUser.Enabled = Enabled;
        returnUser.Email = Email;
        returnUser.NTLogin = NTLogin;
        returnUser.Login = Login;
        returnUser.Password = Password;
        returnUser.PasswordAttemptFailCount = PasswordAttemptFailCount;

        return returnUser;
    }
```

Comment: Potentially your SQL Server DateTime settings are different to your .NET environment. I.e. one is US and one UK

Comment: What does `GetBaseObject` do? Quick search of the net gives me nothing.

Comment: Please provide the code for "GetBaseObject" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I've found my noob error posting the code :-(

I rewrite the value of dates during GetBaseObject() ....

It useful to post the code here ^^ you see the errors very well. Better than in my Visual Studio :-P that I used every time.

Thanks all to your participation

Comment: Next time, [talk to your duck first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).